# insert text on image[2], python

Tags: python, image, text

In my project I need to load an image an display a text in it, but the text needs to be written after executing the application. I tried using `tkinter` but it didn't give me the desired result, so I was wondering, can I add a text in my image using the console of `spyder` ? I mean I display the image, I write my text in the console, and once I hit `enter` The text is shown in  my image.
via this link you'll find my attempt in doing it using `tkinter`. [insert text on image, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352381/insert-text-on-image-python)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy to do, for those who might need it, here is the code to do it:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

img = Image.open('rect.png')

var = input("Please enter something: ")
print ("you entered", var)


font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 20)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0,0), var, (255,255,0), font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("a_test.png")

img.show()
```