# Color lines seperately in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a music program that would display [Chordpro](https://www.chordpro.org/) files in python. Similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvWTj.png), I want the chords, comments, and lyrics to each have different colours. I've tried these **widgets:**

I tried separating chords, comments and lyrics into multiple strings that could overlap on a **canvas** (with a different colour for each string) to make the full song, but sadly whitespace overrides previously rendered text, so I could only see the last layer.

**Label/Message** doesn't have functionality for multiple colours unless make a label for each line, which is very tedious, considering I want the font size to be adjustable too.

**Text** is editable, which I don't want.

*Is there some kind of module or other tkinter widget that would allow separately coloured lines?*

Comment: You can make the Text widget as read_only by configure it with `state=disabled`. Note you need to set the state to `normal`by inserting something. To get the idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63412737/13629335

Comment: I don't understand your comment about whitespace overriding previously rendered text. I don't see that when I write one word on top of another. Any place in the second string that has whitespace, I see the characters underneath. As for the Text widget, it has the abillity to be made read-only.

Comment: To clarify, when you say "lines" do you mean "lines of text"? When talking about the Canvas, it has the ability to draw actual lines.

Comment: @BryanOakley I probably messed something up with the canvas then. With lines I meant lines of text. But it doesn't matter anymore, I made it work by using the Text widget :)

Answer (score 0):

Just draw the separate lines at different y positions (heights) on the canvas.  It's the first two parameters of the create_text() function.  E.g.

```
self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=650, bg = '#afeeee')
self.canvas.create_text(100,10,fill="darkblue",font="Times 20 italic bold",
                    text="Greensleeves are my...")
```

So here, change 10 to the line position you want etc.  Code copied from [Python: how to add text inside a canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736967/python-how-to-add-text-inside-a-canvas)